# Implementing nonlinear optimization with nonlinear inequality constraints with java

Tags: java, apache, nonlinear-optimization

How do I implement a nonlinear optimization with nonlinear constraints in java? I am currently using org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv, and I have read that none of the optimizers (such as the one I am currently working with, SimplexOptimizer) take constraints by default, but that instead one must map the constrained parameters to unconstrained ones by implementing the MultivariateFunctionPenaltyAdapter or MultivariateFunctionMappingAdapter classes. However, as far as I can tell, even using these wrappers, one can still only implement linear or "simple" constraints. I am wondering if there is any way to include nonlinear inequality constraints?

For example, suppose that My objective function is a function of 3 parameters: a,b,and c (depending on them non-linearly) and that additionally these parameters are subject to the constraint that ab

Any advice that would solve the problem using just apache commons would be great, but any suggestions for extending existing classes or augmenting the package would also be welcome of course.

My best attempt so far at implementing the COBYLA package is given below:

```
    public static double[] Optimize(double[][] contractDataMatrix,double[] minData, double[] maxData,double[] modelData,String modelType,String weightType){

    ObjectiveFunction objective = new ObjectiveFunction(contractDataMatrix,modelType,weightType);

     double rhobeg = 0.5;
    double rhoend = 1.0e-6;
   int iprint = 3;
     int maxfun = 3500;
    int n = modelData.length;
    Calcfc calcfc = new Calcfc(){
       @Override
       public double Compute(int n, int m, double[] x, double[] con){
        con[0]=x[3]*x[3]-2*x[0]*x[1];
        System.out.println("constraint: "+(x[3]*x[3]-2*x[0]*x[1]));
        return objective.value(x);
       }
    };
    COBYLAExitStatus result = COBYLA.FindMinimum(calcfc, n, 1, modelData, rhobeg, rhoend, iprint, maxfun);


    return modelData;

}
```

The issue is that I am still getting illegal values in my optimization. As you can see, within the anonymous override of the compute function, I am printing out the value of my constraint. The result is often negative. But shouldn't this value be constrainted to be non-negative?

EDIT: I found the bug in my code, which was unrelated to the optimizer itself but rather my implementation.

Best,

Paul

Comment: The COBYLA optimizer is not restricted to the feasible region during the optimization, so in a specific iteration the constraint values may very well be negative. At successful convergence however, the constraint values should be non-negative (within a tolerance propoprtional to RHOEND).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider an optimizer that is not available in *Apache Commons Math*. [COBYLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBYLA) is a derivative-free method for relatively small optimization problems (less than 100 variables) with nonlinear constraints. I have ported the original Fortran code to Java, the source code is [here](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla).

Comment: Hi Anders, thank you for your response. I have tried using your classes, but I am getting an error when I try to build your project. I copied and pasted the three classes in the "src" file of your project into my project folder, but I am getting one error: In the Cobyla class, the overriden method "Compute" is giving a compile error: "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". Is this something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: What compilation error are you receiving? Have you tried to compile the code on its own e.g. in Netbeans? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: the compile error I received is quoted above. I am using java jre7. I am not sure what you mean by "compile on its own"... if I put the three source files alone in a project folder, I get the same error.

Comment: When you copied the files, did you put them in a new path? Did you then change the package names consistently in all files? Did you include the Calcfc.java file as well, which provides the supertype in question? 
I just now imported the project myself and successfully built and ran the unit tests.

Comment: Yes to all of the above questions, except the first. I created new blank files in my project folder and then copied and pasted the .java files in your src directory, and then changed all of the package names appropriately.

Comment: Anders, I have gotten the package to work, and I have edited my post above to show my best efforts to implement it. As I explain in my edited post, I am still getting constraint function values that are negative. Do you know why this might be the case?